# How do you customize the drop highlight for a NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, highlight

The highlighting I want is for it to draw the drop indicator between rows and to never highlight an entire row. How can I do this with the 10.5 SDK?

Since I am using the 10.5 SDK, I don't have access to -setDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle: which is available in the 10.6 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the `‑tableView:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedDropOperation:` table datasource method and return `NSTableViewDropAbove` rather than `NSTableViewDropOn` for the rows in question.

As per [the docs,](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004178) to propose a drop below the last row, row would be `[aTableView numberOfRows]` and operation would be `NSTableViewDropAbove`.